# Jquery query string match and change selected Href

Tags: jquery, query-string

I am trying to find one param in query string and handle two things. 
Example url - `http://domainname.com?name=y&track=1&promo=true`

1. Append those query string to all the url's on the page - this is fine I believe.
2. Change the href url itself for the urls that contains specific string in it and then append the query string. These href are there in different ways such as a href tag, onclick inside image tag.

   `<a href="http://externaldomain.com/?a=88">link</a>, <img src="a.jpg" onclick = document.location.href="http://externaldomain.com/?a=88" />`

Code so far to do the first thing

```js
var querystring = window.location.search.substring(0);
var newurl = "http://changetothisdomain.com/"; //for second criteria
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, value) {
    if ((querystring.indexOf("promo=true") > 0) && (value.indexOf('#') != 0)) {
      return value + querystring;
    }
  });
});
```

I have this value.indexOf('#')!=0 so that the urls with # are not changed because it is for jquery tabs. Adding parameters to these affects that. For the second thing, I want to check if promo=true is there in querystring and then also check if href has "a=88" then change the href to "newurl" and append querystring.

Thanks!

Comment: I was on my phone and tried to give you ONE script that is more generic so you can do `if (getParm("promo")=="true" && getParm("a")=="88")` Since you did not use such a script, I assumed you had not found it

Comment: ok thanks. it was not clear with just search link so i replied that way. will look into getparam method. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - it was NOT trivial

```js
var querystring = "?blabla=bla&promo=true&bla=bla"; //  window.location.search;
var newurl = "http://changetothisdomain.com/"; //for second criteria

function changeURL(value) {
  if (value.indexOf('#') == 0) return value;
  return (value.indexOf("a=88") == -1 ? value : newurl) + querystring;
}

function changeString(value) {
  if (value.indexOf('#') == 0) return value;
  var match = value.match(/href=([^"]*)/);
  var url = (match.length > 0) ? match[1] : "";
  var replace = url.indexOf("a=88") == -1 ? url : newurl;
  var qString = (replace.indexOf("?") !=-1)?querystring:"&"+querystring.substring(1);
  if (url.indexOf("'") != -1) {
    replace = replace.replace(/'/g, "");
    replace = "'" + replace + qString + "'";
  } else if (url.indexOf('"') != -1) {
    replace = replace.replace(/"/g, "");
    replace = '"' + replace + qString + '"';
  }
  return value.replace(url, replace);
}

$(function() {
  if (querystring.indexOf("promo=true") != -1) {
    $('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, value) {
      return changeURL(value);
    });
    $('img').attr('onclick', function(index, value) {
      return changeString(value);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://externaldomain.com/?href=true&a=88">link</a>,
<img src="a.jpg" onclick="document.location.href='http://externaldomain.com/?img=true&a=88'" />
<a href="http://externaldomain.com/?href=true&a=89">link</a>,
<img src="a.jpg" onclick="document.location.href='http://externaldomain.com/?img=true&a=88'" />
```